# OpenCV error "Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated." after starting training stage-3

Tags: opencv, ocr

While searching for this error I only found cases where it happened right at the beginning. In my case, it occurred at the beginning of the 3-stage training.

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.10, with OpenMP enabled. Bellow is the command line I used and the output. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

```
root@6b0f88eaadb9:/opt/ocr-samples3/train-detector# opencv_traincascade -data ./out// -vec ./positive/vecfile.vec -bg ./negative/negative.txt -w 247 -h 80 -numPos 78 -numNeg 1325 -featureType LBP -numStages 8
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Training parameters are loaded from the parameter file in data folder!
Please empty the data folder if you want to use your own set of parameters.
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: ./out//
vecFileName: ./positive/vecfile.vec
bgFileName: ./negative/negative.txt
numPos: 78
numNeg: 1325
numStages: 8
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 256
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 256
stageType: BOOST
featureType: LBP
sampleWidth: 247
sampleHeight: 80
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   78 : 78
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    1325 : 1
Precalculation time: 6
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|0.0211321|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 1 hours 22 minutes 40 seconds.

===== TRAINING 1-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   78 : 78
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    1325 : 0.0928456
Precalculation time: 10
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1|0.0324528|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 3 hours 19 minutes 57 seconds.

===== TRAINING 2-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   78 : 78
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    1325 : 0.00679104
Precalculation time: 7
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|     0.08|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 4 hours 38 minutes 25 seconds.

===== TRAINING 3-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   78 : 78
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

How big are you negative images. I had the same problem. The error say that he hasn't enough negative images. Your negative images doe not have to be the same size as your  positive. So what I did take the original negative images but a black rectangle on the object. And started again.

*The function negative search in the image for new negative images, when he used one negative image he will not use it again. It randomly chosen and has the same size as your positive image.*